# for Canon MF3010

Tags: drivers, printing, canon

I try to install my printer. From previous experience and research, for ubuntu 16.10, I installed appropriate drivers for Linux 64 bit that is given by Canon for MF 3010. Everything fine. But, after try to use the printer, it does not work. I upgraded cups libraries, again it does not work.

I dont know what to do? any idea so as to connect my printer.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

You need to download the **UFR II/UFRII LT Printer Driver for Linux V3.31** provided by Canon.

You can download it at https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/black-and-white-laser/mf3010/imageclass-mf3010?tab=drivers_downloads (thank you Xaqron)

Connect your printer with your computer, download the linux-UFRII-drv-v331-uken.tar.gz, extract it, go in the folder with the terminal and type

> $ sudo ./install.sh

and confirm with `y`

[image]

After the installation go to `System Settings->Printers->Add->Canon MF3010`

You can now use your printer!

Comment: The latest version of the Linux Drivers, v3.50, are located here. 32/64 Bit: http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100924010.html

Comment: Official website link: https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/support/details/printers/black-and-white-laser/mf3010/imageclass-mf3010?tab=drivers_downloads

Comment: @Xaqron thank you for mentioning, I updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04 (driver version V5.20) `install.sh` didnt work for me with various errors.

so I installed the deb file alone

```
sudo dpkg -i linux-UFRII-drv-v520-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian/cnrdrvcups-ufr2-uk_5.20-1_amd64.deb
```

after this both printer and scanner seems to work fine.